# How to appear item from localStorage to DOM

Tags: javascript

I get items from local storage by `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'))`.

This is an array of objects and I need to appear in it DOM each other in `listItemElement`.

How it is possible? I need to when refreshing these values from `localStorage` is appear in DOM. When refreshing I need to appear and buttons.

I tried to appendChild to `listItemElement`, but it is going on at the end of this.

Thank you!

This is JS:

```
function handleSaveButton() {
    // STEP 1: Apply to State.
    let listItem = {
        title: titleInputElement.value,
        time: seconds,
        description: descriptionField.value,
        isDetailsShown: false,
    };

    listState.push(listItem);

    // STEP 2: Resetting value of input elements.
    descriptionField.value = '';
    titleInputElement.value = '';

    // STEP 3: Create list item.
    const listItemElement = document.createElement('li');

    // STEP 4: Create list item title.
    const titleSpanElement = document.createElement('span');
    const separatorSpanElement = document.createElement('span');

    titleSpanElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(listItem.title));
    listItemElement.appendChild(titleSpanElement);
    listItemElement.appendChild(separatorSpanElement);

    if (listItem.title.length > 0) {
        separatorSpanElement.innerText = ' - ';
    }

    // STEP 5: Create list item time.
    listItemElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatHours(seconds)))

    // STEP 6: Create 'Input' field for title.
    const textInputBox = document.createElement('input');
    textInputBox.setAttribute('type', 'text');

    // STEP 7: Create 'Edit' button.
    const titleEditButton = document.createElement('button');
    titleEditButton.innerText = 'Edit';
    titleEditButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        textInputBox.value = listItem.title;
        titleSpanElement.replaceWith(textInputBox);

        if (textInputBox.value.length === 0) {
            separatorSpanElement.innerText = ' - ';
        }

        titleEditButton.replaceWith(titleSaveButton);
    });

    listItemElement.appendChild(titleEditButton);

    // STEP 8: Create 'Save' button in Edit state.
    const titleSaveButton = document.createElement('button');
    titleSaveButton.innerText = 'Save';
    titleSaveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        listItem.title = textInputBox.value;
        localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(listState));

        titleSpanElement.innerText = listItem.title;

        if (listItem.title === 0) {
            separatorSpanElement.innerText = '';
        }

        textInputBox.replaceWith(titleSpanElement);
        titleSaveButton.replaceWith(titleEditButton);
    });

    // STEP 9: Create a 'Details' button.
    const detailsButton = document.createElement('button');
    detailsButton.innerText = 'Details';

    detailsButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // STEP 1: Handle already shown item.
        const shownItem = listState.find(listItem => listItem.isDetailsShown);

        if (shownItem !== undefined && shownItem !== listItem) {
            detailsContainer.remove();
            shownItem.isDetailsShown = false;
        }

        // STEP 2: Handle currently clicked item.
        if (!listItem.isDetailsShown) {
            detailsContainer = document.createElement('div');

            const lineSeparator = document.createElement('hr');
            detailsContainer.appendChild(lineSeparator);

            const titleParagraphElement = document.createElement('p');
            titleParagraphElement.innerText = `Title: ${listItem.title}`;
            detailsContainer.appendChild(titleParagraphElement);

            const descriptionParagraphElement = document.createElement('p');
            descriptionParagraphElement.innerText = `Description: ${listItem.description}`;
            detailsContainer.appendChild(descriptionParagraphElement);

            const timeParagraphElement = document.createElement('p');
            timeParagraphElement.innerText = `Time: ${formatHours(listItem.time)}`;
            detailsContainer.appendChild(timeParagraphElement);

            document.body.appendChild(detailsContainer);

        } else {
            detailsContainer.remove();
        }

        listItem.isDetailsShown = !listItem.isDetailsShown;
    });

    listItemElement.appendChild(detailsButton);

    // STEP 10: Create 'Remove' button.
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.innerText = 'Remove';
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        const idx = listState.indexOf(listItem);

        if (idx > -1) {
            listState.splice(idx, 1);
            localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(listState));
        }

        listItemElement.remove();
    });

    listItemElement.appendChild(removeButton);

    // STEP 11: Add list item to list.
    listElement.appendChild(listItemElement);

    localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(listState));

    const itemByLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'));

    for (const i of itemByLocal) {
        
    }
};
```

Comment: So your real problem is adding DOM object based on an array?

Comment: It seems like you already know how to add a `listItem` to the DOM. However, all of this is currently happening only in the `handleSaveButton` function, not when the page is loaded from the items in `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'))`.

Comment: Yes, my problem is how I can add data from localStorage to DOM when I refresh the page. My `listItemElement` is declared in this `handleSaveButton` function and I can't access it outside. What I need to do when `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'))`

Comment: Would you specify what you have tried and what were the problems you have faced? I see that you are successfully getting the data from the localStorage but I'm not sure why it is in a function that appears to be handling a button click (`handleSaveButton`). Also why are you trying to access `listItemElement` outside the function? Couldn't you recreate it as it is doing on every click on save button?